# Simplify this derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to differentiate the below and simplify to the simplest terms. I hope to find someone who can review my algebra and let me know if I've made a mistake in the process. Thank you for your help:

$$y = \frac{r}{(r^2+1)^{1/2}}$$
First apply quotient rule and chain rules:
$$y'=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(r^2+1)^{-1/2}(2r)(r)-(1)(r^2+1)^{1/2}}{(r^2+1)^{1/2*2}}$$

In the numerator: $(r)*(2r)*(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{2r^2}{2}=r^2$

We now have:
$$y'=\frac{(r^2)(r^2+1)^{-1/2}-(r^2+1)^{1/2}}{(r^2+1)^1}$$

In the numerator, $(r^2+1)^{-1/2}$ is a negative exponent. Flip it below the denominator to make it positive and rewrite all fractional exponents in the expression as roots:

$$y'=\frac{(r^2)-\sqrt{(r^2+1)}}{\sqrt{(r^2+1)}*(r^2+1)}$$

Cancellation of $\sqrt{r^2+1}$:
$$\frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1}$$

Cancellation of $r^2$:
$$=-1$$

Where did my algebra go wrong? The textbook solution is:
$y'=(r^2+1)^{-3/2}$

Thank you for your help. Source: Stewart, James. Calculus Early Transcendentals, 7th Ed. 2012

Comment: Are you sure your cancellation of $r^2$ step makes any sense?

Comment: @HritikNarayan It’s the sort of thing that you can find in this old [JIR article](http://www.textfiles.com/humor/COMPUTER/maths.txt) :)

Comment: Ok I see the flaw in my math. The cancellation of $\sqrt{r^2+1}$ can't be done because the numerator is not an identical factor to the denominator. This is because the numerator is an entire term. The denominator is two terms. The second cancellation of $r^2$ is definitely not possible because the terms are different. I can't split apart terms and call their individual pieces identical factors because the expression's arithmetic will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the quotient rule $\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{f(r)}{g(r)}\right)=\frac{g(r)f'(r)-f(r)g'(r)}{(g(r))^2}$ and chain rule, we have:
$$\begin{align}y&=\frac{r}{(r^2+1)^{1/2}}\\\frac{dy}{dr}&=\frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2}(1)-r\frac12(r^2+1)^{-1/2}(2r)}{r^2+1}\qquad\text{applying quotient rule}\\&=(r^2+1)^{-1/2}\frac{r^2+1-r^2}{r^2+1}\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{factoring out} (r^2+1)^{-1/2}\\&=\frac{1}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, your cancellation of $\sqrt{r^2+1}$ is wrong. It doesn't multiply $r^2$ and so doesn't actually cancel. And of course, the cancellation of $r^2$ is wrong for the same reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can cancel only when what you are cancelling is a factor of the entire denominator and the entire numerator.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. I think this was a forgotten gap in my math learning that has been hurting me for a long, long time. After doing some further reading I understand that that an identical factor must be a stand-alone term in its respective numerator or denominator. No splitting of terms in the expression.

Comment: Also “flipping the radical below the denominator” is an interesting technique. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite as

$$\left(1+\frac1{r^2}\right)^{-1/2}.$$

Then the derivative is

$$-\frac2{r^3}\left(-\frac12\right)\left(1+\frac1{r^2}\right)^{-3/2}=(r^2+1)^{-3/2}.$$

---

Or by the logarithmic derivative,

$$y'=(\log y)'y=\left(\log r-\frac12\log(r^2+1)\right)'y=\left(\frac1r-\frac r{r^2+1}\right)y=\frac1{r(r^2+1)}y=\frac1{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$y'=\frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2}-r^2(r^2+1)^{-1/2}}{r^2+1}$$ multiplying numerator and denominator by $$(r^2+1)^{1/2}$$ we obtain
$$y'=\frac{r^2+1-r^2}{(r^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule step looks negated.  The derivative of $\dfrac {P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is $ \dfrac{QP' - PQ'}{Q^2}$, not $\dfrac{PQ' - QP'}{Q^2}$.  So this will give you
$$ y' = \frac{(r^2+1)^{1/2} \cdot (1) - r \cdot \frac{1}{2} (r^2 + 1)^{-3/2} \cdot 2r}{r^2+1},$$
where the $2r$ at the end of the numerator comes from the chain rule.  Can you take it from here?